# Exothermic reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-coordinate

[image]

Please someone explain me the solution of this question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! At this point I suggest you do a couple things. First, take the short [tour] to familiarize yourself with how this site works. Secondly, this is not a "homework" site. You will need to show some work and effort to start off with before others will put their efforts into helping you. How far can you get? What specifically don't you understand? [This](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) post give some good guidance for asking homework questions. Best of luck with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question tells you that the reaction is exothermic, so option 4 is out as the products are at a higher energy than reactants.

Now we see that $\ce{A + B -> X}$ is the slow step or rate determining step of the reaction, so it needs a higher activation energy than the step $\ce{X -> AB}$.

This eliminates the option 1. Option 2 is nowhere close to a right answer as the intermediate is nowhere to be seen. Thus we see that option 3 satisfies all our conditions and hence comes out to be the answer.